# C# OpenApi Json String response

Tags: c#, openapi

I am trying to print a Json String in OpenAPI response body, however all the escaped characters are printed, so it is not easy readable for the user. Ex: `

> {\r\n\t"Name": "xxxx",\r\n\t"Version": "V1",\r\n\t"Platform":
> "xxxx",\r\n\t"IsPuppetAgentServiceControllerRequired":
> true,\r\n\t"AgentUrl":
> "http://www.example.com",\r\n\t"Modules":\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"module1":\r\n\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t"propertyname1":
> "value1",\r\n\t\t\t"propertyname2":
> "value2",\r\n\t\t\t"propertyname3": "value3"\r\n\t\t}...

I would like to show something like this:

```
{   
  Name: xxxxx,   
  Version: xxxx,   
  Module1: {
     property: value,
     property: value ....
```

The response is dynamically generated, it doesn't follow a predefined structure, so I can not add it to the scheme. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you check your JSON string again. It is missing " quotes in the values? "Name": xxxx should be "Name": "xxxx". Is that intended?

Comment: And I see many of these keys propertyname as duplicates.

Comment: I just correct the ", it was an error from when I replace the values for xxxx, about the propertyname were just examples, I just add a number at the end on each of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a valid Json string from the API as I commented, If your intention is to just `print` without escape characters then you could you use the [`Regex.Unescape`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Unescape_System_String_)

```
 string readText = "<Your json String";
 string str = Regex.Unescape(readText);
//OUTPUT
{
  "Name": "xxxx",
  "Version": "V1",
  "Platform": "xxxx",
  "IsPuppetAgentServiceControllerRequired": true,
  "AgentUrl": "http://www.example.com",
  "Modules": {
    "module1": {
      "propertyname": "value"
    }
  }
}
```

The get output you mentioned in your question the use [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) using `parse` method on escaped string as mentioned above code.

```
 var testStr = JObject.Parse(str);       
                       
 foreach (var pair in testStr)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
EditedText = JsonText.Replace("\n", '\n');
```

You can use similar methodology to achieve what you are looking for.